# Php array from multiple checkbox

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm working with laravel, and I'm a bit stuck in getting the right structure I want of the value, so I have a check box like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="permission[]" value="{{$permission->slug}}"> {{$permission->name}}
```

And this outputs me this:

```
array:2 [
    0 => "dashboard.view"
    1 => "user.edit"
]
```

But what I really need to store is something like this:

```
{"dashboard.view":true,"user.edit":true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="permission[{{$permission->slug}}]" value="true"> {{$permission->name}}
```

Should give you an associative array on the backend you can call `json_encode` on if you need to store it as a json object.

Comment: Yeah it works to, there is any way to get the unchecked ones? without an hidden field

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) function to exchange keys with values, and then to make json string you can call [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)